# Site crashing, Can't create/write to file '/tmp

Tags: mysql, question2answer

I have a site that is using `question2answer` script and some custom made code.
I recently have a problem with the site crashing. The error I get when I open the page is:

Database query error 1
`Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_819_0.MYI' (Errcode: 13)`

```
(SELECT 'options' AS selectkey, title, content FROM qa_options) UNION ALL (SELECT 'time', 'db_time', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))
```

All seems to be fine with the tmp permissions: `drwxrwxrwt`

I don't know when this is happening. If I restart the server everything is working fine and I get no errors. Then, after some time it is happening again. Site is down and all I get is that message.

Really need your help!

Comment: Free space? You might have run out of disk space. Check with `df -h`

Comment: Crashing is when your program breaks for some reason.  Crushing is when an elephant sits on your DB server :-)

Comment: Checked to see if I'm running of free space, but it is not the case. 990M still free in /tmp , only one percent used

Comment: OS error code  13:  Permission denied
So it does not look like a space problem.

Comment: Can someone explain what drwxrwxrwt means?

Comment: Those are the file permissions:
d- directory
r- red, w - write, x - execute
rwx repeats three times once each for owner, group, others